# pthread_mutex_t inside a structure and locking the structure when accessing

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have global structure pointer which i have done a malloc (array of 10 structures) and i have sent one instance of this structure to each thread, and before passing this structure instance as argument to pthread_create(), am updating the structure member value. Inside each thread i will lock and print the member value.

I have created another thread, in which i am passing the entire structure instance, i am locking each structure instance and printing it, but every time it prints 0. Can you please suggest what changes i have to  make.

I dont want to use any thread conditions, as i am sleeping in each thread for a thread switch.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h> 
#include<pthread.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 

struct lock_check{
    int value;
    pthread_mutex_t lock; 
}; 
struct lock_check *check;

void* trythis(void *arg) 
{
    struct lock_check *thread = (struct lock_check *)arg;
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&thread->lock); 
        printf("Inside Thread with value:%d\n", thread->value); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread->lock); 
        sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL; 
}

void* printthis(void *arg) 
{
    printf("Entering printthis thread\n");
    struct lock_check *print_thread = (struct lock_check *)arg;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&print_thread[i].lock); 
        printf("Printing value :%d\n", print_thread[i].value); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&print_thread[i].lock); 
    }
    return NULL; 
}
int main(void) 
{ 
    int i = 0; 
    int error; 
    check = malloc(sizeof(struct lock_check) * 10);
    pthread_t tid[10];
    pthread_t tid_read;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        check[i].value = i;
        error = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &trythis, &check[i]); 
        if (error != 0) 
            printf("\nThread can't be created :[%s]", strerror(error)); 
    }
    sleep(5);
    printf("creating printthis thread\n");
    error = pthread_create(&tid_read, NULL, &printthis, &check);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); 
    }
    pthread_join(tid_read, NULL); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It also appears that you are invoking undefined behavior: ["If `mutex` does not refer to an initialized `mutex` object, the behavior of `pthread_mutex_lock()`, `pthread_mutex_trylock()`, and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` is undefined."](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) Where do you initialize the mutex with [`pthread_mutex_init()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle:  can you please suggest me a better approach, as per my requirement i pass each structure instance to each thread and there will be one more thread which has to read data from each of structure instance

Answer (score 0):

```
error = pthread_create(&tid_read, NULL, &printthis, &check);
```

`pthread_create` is expecting `void *` but you are passing `struct lock_check **` having undefined behavior.

Change it to.

```
error = pthread_create(&tid_read, NULL, &printthis, check);
```

Comment: As written this answer is wrong, or "right for the wrong reason". The differing type does not cause UB. All pointer types (pointer to pointer is a pointer type) convert to and round-trip through `void *` just fine. The problem is that it points to the wrong thing (the local pointer variable `check`, whereas the thread start function expects it to point to the structure `check` pointed to).